# Unnest a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column (details) in a pandas dataframe (df) which contains data that looks like this:

| ID | details |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | list('name' = 'Something', 'description' = 'What something is') |
| 2 | list('name' = 'Something Else', 'description' = 'Another description') |

I'm trying to unnest this column and return two columns (details_name and details_description).

Running `type(df.details.iloc[0])` returns <class 'dict'>

I tried:

```
df = (df
.assign(details_name=df.details.apply(lambda x: x['name']))
.assign(details_description=df.details.apply(lambda x: x['description']))
)
```

But that returned *KeyError: 'name'*.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `type(df.details.iloc[0]) returns <class 'dict'>` are you sure? your table in the post shows a list object? can you post a screenshot or the original data as a code block isntead of markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your data looks like this (based on the type command you show and NOT based on the markdown table)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2],
                  'details':[{'name' : 'Something', 'description' : 'What something is'},
                             {'name' : 'Something Else', 'description' : 'Another description'}]})

type(df.details.iloc[0])
```

```
dict
```

In order to separate the keys into columns you can just convert the `dict` to series and pandas will automatically separate them as columns for you.

```
df[['details_name','details_description']] = df.details.apply(pd.Series) #<-----

print(df.drop('details', axis=1))
```

```
   ID    details_name  details_description
0   1       Something    What something is
1   2  Something Else  Another description
```

Comment: glad to help anytime.

Comment: Also thanks for making the assumption with regards to how my data looks. I'm new to python and I'll get better at posting questions.

Comment: All good, its better to post the raw table in a code block instead of a table as markdown (even though its more formatted). Reason is that someone can simply copy-paste the data from a code block and test a solution.. but for markdown, they will have to re-write the dataset from scratch.